# What does <<EOF do?

Tags: linux, unix, administrator

I am a newbie in Linux admin and while I'm learning GDB to debug my code, I need to create an `input.txt` file for my program to read. I know redirection symbols such as `>`, `>>`, and `<`, but couldn't find info about `<<` via Google since it ignores it.

What does the `<<EOF` do below?

```
cat >input.txt <<EOF
```

Comment: See the Stack Exchange post: [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/80216)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

An excerpt from [Shell Input/Output Redirections](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-io-redirections.htm):

> **Here Document** 
>  A here document is used to redirect input into an interactive shell script or program. We can run an interactive program within a shell script without user action by supplying the required input for the interactive program, or interactive shell script.
>
> - The general form for a here document is:
>
>   ```bash
>   command << delimiter
>   document
>   delimiter
>   ```
>
>   Here the shell interprets the `<<` operator as an instruction to read input until it finds a line containing the specified delimiter. All the input lines up to the line containing the delimiter are then fed into the standard input of the command. 
>    The delimiter tells the shell that the here document has completed. Without it, the shell continues to read input forever. The delimiter must be a single word that does not contain spaces or tabs.
> - Following is the input to the command `wc -l` to count total number of line:
>
>   ```bash
>   $wc -l << EOF
>   This is a simple lookup program for good (and bad) restaurants in Cape Town.
>   EOF
>   3
>   ```
> - You can use here document to print multiple lines using your script:
>
>   ```bash
>   #!/bin/sh
>
>   cat << EOF
>   This is a simple lookup program for good (and bad) restaurants in Cape Town.
>   EOF
>   ```
>
>   This would produce:
>
>   ```bash
>   This is a simple lookup program for good (and bad) restaurants in Cape Town.
>   ```
> - This runs a session with the `vi` text editor and saves the input in the file `test.txt`:
>
>   ```bash
>   #!/bin/sh
>
>   filename=test.txt
>
>   vi $filename <<EndOfCommands
>   i
>   This file was created automatically from a shell script
>   ^[
>   ZZ
>   EndOfCommands
>   ```
> - If you run this script with `vim` acting as `vi`, then you will likely see output like:
>
>   ```bash
>   $ sh test.sh
>     Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
>   ```
>
>   After running the script, you should see the following added to `test.txt`:
>
>   ```bash
>   $ cat test.txt
>     This file was created automatically from a shell script
>   ```

Comment: +1 for the Cape Town reference haha

Comment: Your `wc` example returns 1 not 3, for me.

Answer (score 1):

CAT< New.txt (Press Enter)
Here, the user will be prompted to type the input to the file "New.txt". Then Press the Cntrl+d command to tell that this is the End of the file.

Instead of using cntrl+d, **Cat<<EOF** command can be used in this scenario and type EOF at the end of the paragraph. The system will consider EOF as the End of the para. Instead of EOF, any alphabets can be used.
eg) CAT<<ZZZ New.txt (Press Enter).
Here, the User will be prompted to type the input.
At the end of the para, type **ZZZ**, then press enter. The system will consider **ZZZ** as the End of the para and it will come out of it.